# How to add multiple style rules to css pseudo elements using js?

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

I have follwing html, css and js

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" class="name">name</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    position: relative;
}
```

**JS**

```
var styleString = 'content:" ";, width: 0, height: 0;, border-style: solid;, border-width: 100px 100px 0 100px;, border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent;, position: absolute;';

document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.name:after', styleString);
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/chzqsdcu/)**

My question is only the content: " " is getting added and the rest of the rules are missing. What is the wrong with my code?

Comment: remove commas and use semicolons to seperate attributes

Comment: Why do you add a comma after each semicolon? Extra comma I would say.

Comment: @user4759923 wow thanks i was acting stupid thanks

Comment: you'd be better off adding the css selector and the set of styes to the css file then using js to add and remove a class as required, then your css rules are easier to re-use and your js is a lot less cluttered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @MoshFeu has already pointed out, the commas after each `;` are not necessary and should be removed:

The full code:

```
var styleString = 'content:" "; width: 0; height: 0; border-style: solid; border-width: 100px 100px 0 100px; border-color: #007bff transparent transparent transparent; position: absolute;';

document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.name:after', styleString);
```

Comment: This code will not work too. He needs to remove the `,`

Comment: Thanks friend. The css is for a css triangle. the  width is not needed so it should be 0. I figured that the problem with my code was that extra `,` as @MoshFeu pointed.. :)